# BlackBerry Browser: weird text wrapping behavior

Tags: html, browser, blackberry, word-wrap

When viewing the following test page with the browser in the BlackBerry 9630 simulator, the text width is wider than the screen width. So, when zoomed to 100%, one has to pan.

http://sites.inka.de/klee/blackberry/text.html

What solutions are there to make the text wrap to screen width?

Comment: I tried with a 8330 and a 9550 Simulator, and it is working perfectly. Maybe putting your text within <p></p> could fix your problem.

Comment: Putting the text in paragraph tags doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
<body style="margin: 0">
```

With the default margin, after loading the page, the cursor has the shape of a magnifying glass, allowing the user to zoom in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The browser has a default width for the window, when you zoom, the window keep it's full width, so every website will have this problem.

You can't fix this, since it's an expected behavior.

If you don't want your user to zoom on your website, make the font bigger.

Comment: I was able to fix it - see my reply.